# Generate the Norwegian equivalent to social security numbers - follow-up

Tags: c++, classes, datetime, validation, inheritance

First of, [**here**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55870/generate-the-norwegian-equivalent-to-social-security-numbers) is my previous post.

That should explain a fair bit. The reason I'm posting one more time, is I have changed a lot. Using more classes, let them do all the work, and the overall structure.

```
#include <iostream>

const int DATE_LENGTH = 6;

class Date {
    private:
        char *ans;
    protected:
        int date[DATE_LENGTH];
        int year;
    public:
        Date() {
            askForDate();
        }

        ~Date() {
            if(ans) { delete ans; }
        }

        void askForDate() {
            using namespace std;
            ans = new char[DATE_LENGTH];
            cout << "Date of Birth (DDMMYY): ";         cin.getline(ans, DATE_LENGTH + 1);
            while (!validDate(ans)) {
                cin.getline(ans, DATE_LENGTH + 1);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < DATE_LENGTH; i++) { date[i] = int(ans[i] - '0'); }
            year = 1900 + date[4] * 10 + date[5];
        }

        bool validDate(const char *d) {
            return strlen(d) == 6;
        }
};

class IndividSiffer : public Date {
    protected:
        int i1, i2, i3; 
    public:
        IndividSiffer(int ii1, int ii2, int ii3) : i1(ii1), i2(ii2), i3(ii3) {}

        void individSiffer() {
            static int individ = -1;
            if(year >= 1900 && year <= 1999 ){
                individ++;
                i1 = i2 = i3 = 0;
            }
            i3 = individ % 10;
            if(individ < 100){
                i1 = 0;
                i2 = individ / 10 % 10;
            }else if(individ < 10){
                i1 = i2 = 0;
            }else{
                i1 = individ / 100 % 10;
                i2 = individ / 10 % 10;
            }
        }
};

class KontrollSiffer : public IndividSiffer {
    protected:
        int k1, k2;
    public:
        KontrollSiffer(int kk1 = 0, int kk2 = 0, int i1 = 0, int i2 = 0, int i3 = 0) : IndividSiffer(i1, i2, i3), k1(kk1), k2(kk2) {
            for (int index = 0; index < 500; index++) {
                individSiffer();
                generate();
            }
        }

        void generate() {
            using namespace std;
            k1 = 11 - ((3*date[0] + 7*date[1] + 6*date[2] + 1*date[3] + 8*date[4] + 9*date[5] + 4*i1 + 5*i2 + 2*i3) % 11); 
            if(k1 == 11){ k1 = 0; }
            k2 = 11 - ((5*date[0] + 4*date[1] + 3*date[2] + 2*date[3] + 7*date[4] + 6*date[5] + 5*i1 + 4*i2 + 3*i3 + 2*k1) % 11);
            if(k2 == 11){ k2 = 0; }
            if((i3 != 0 && i3 != 2 && i3 !=4 && i3 !=6 && i3 !=8) && (k1 != 10 && k2 !=10)){
                for (int i = 0; i < DATE_LENGTH; i++) { cout << date[i]; }
                cout << i1 << i2 << i3 << k1 << k2 << endl;
            }   
        }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    KontrollSiffer k;
    return 0;
}
```

I'd really like some input on how I structured it, or if things should be done differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some suggestions which may help you improve your code.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` within your program is generally [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Use the appropriate `#include`s

The code uses the `strlen()` function a number of places but does not `#include <cstring>` which is where that library function is defined.

### Eliminate unused variables

This code declares `main` with arguments `argc` and `argv` in the usual way, but neither `argc` nor `argv` are actually used.  This could be addressed by either declaring `int main()` or by modifying the code to actually use the variables.  There is a third way, which is to declare it as `int main(int, char *[])` but this is not recommended because it's a bit confusing to read.

### Separate I/O from object creation

The `Date` class should not do I/O directly to `std::cout` and `std::cin`.  Better design would be to create a custom inserter and custom extractor for the class to allow but not to force I/O operations for the creation of an object.  For example, your `Date` class might have the following two definitions:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::operator &out, const Date &d);
std::istream &operator>>(std::operator &in, Date &d);
```

The same is true of the `KontrollSiffer` class.

### Perform better error checking for user input

As it is currently written, one can type in "Norway" as the `Date` and the code proceeds to proces that input as though it were a valid date, producing invalid results.  Better would be to include more checking beyond just whether the string is 6 characters long.

### Prefer `std::string` to raw `char *`

The `Date` class uses a raw `char *` but would probably be better served by using `std::string` in this context.

### Use aggregation rather than inheritance for composition

The inheritance mechanism is generally suited for "is-a" relationships.  For example, if one had a `Birthday` class, it might reasonably be derived from a `Date` base class, since a `Birthday` is a `Date`.  However, an `IndividSiffer` is not really a `Date`, but is rather constructed from one, so a better design might either have a `Date` as a private instance variable with the `IndividSiffer` class or to simply accept a `const Date &` variable as an argument to an `IndividSiffer` constructor.

### Don't keep variables you don't need

The `ans` variable is only actually used within the `askForDate()` routine, so there's no reason to keep it as part of the `Date` class.  Better would be to declare it as a local variable within the `askForDate()` function.

### Prefer to avoid using `new` and `delete` directly

The `ans` variable within the `Date::askForDate()` function is small enough to easily fit on the stack, so rather than using `new` to allocate it, better would be to declare it locally within the `askForDate` function as:

```
char ans[DATE_LENGTH];
```

That way, it is automatically created with the correct length and then discarded when the function is complete.

### Think carefully about static variables

The code for `IndividSiffer::individSiffer()` uses a static variable `individ` which is a problem.  When you create two `IndividSiffer` instances in the same program, only the first one will have the variable initialized.  That is because a static variable only gets initialized once before the program is run.  This very greatly limits the use of these classes.

### Consider using a standard container

The effect of the `KontrollSiffer` class is to create and print 500 individual numbers.  Rather than simply print and discard them, it might be more sensible for general use to create a collection of them, perhaps in a `std::vector<IndividSiffer>` for example.

### Omit `return 0`

If your program completes successfully, the `return 0` at the end of `main()` will be generated automatically, so it's not needed in C++ programs.

Answer (score 3):

@Edward has mentioned many great points, but I still have several things to add:

- Since you only use `DATE_LENGTH` within the class (and because it's an integer type), you may make it a `private` member:

  ```
  private static const int DATE_LENGTH = 6;
  ```

  You could also consider naming it in either camelCase or snake_case since all-uppercase is usually reserved for macros (`#define`s).
- It's discouraged to have variables declared/initialized on the same line:

  > ```
  > int i1, i2, i3;
  > ```

  Although they appear to be similar, you still want to make sure that they stand out case they need to be modified or commented:

  ```
  int i1;
  int i2;
  int i3;
  ```

  In addition, there is one fundamental issue: the use of Hungarian notation.  The `i` prefix would refer to `int`, but it's already clear that they're `int`s because *C++ is a strongly-typed language*.  Instead, ditch this notation, and name these variables based on their *real* purpose.
- Instead of having the initializer list items horizontally:

  > ```
  > IndividSiffer(int ii1, int ii2, int ii3) : i1(ii1), i2(ii2), i3(ii3) {}
  > ```

  you can have them vertically:

  ```
  IndividSiffer(int ii1, int ii2, int ii3)
      : i1(ii1)
      , i2(ii2)
      , i3(ii3)
  {}
  ```

  In this way, the list won't reach across the screen, and it'll be easier to add/remove items.

  Another thing to be aware of is that, when using an initializer list, argument and member names *can* be the same (without using `this->`).  The compiler can tell them apart when used this way.
- Since `validateDate()` doesn't modify any data members, it should be `const`.  You should also replace the "magic number" with your `DATE_LENGTH` constant.

  ```
  bool validDate(const char *d) const {
      return strlen(d) == DATE_LENGTH;
  }
  ```
- This is a pretty long line:

  > ```
  > KontrollSiffer(int kk1 = 0, int kk2 = 0, int i1 = 0, int i2 = 0, int i3 = 0) : IndividSiffer(i1, i2, i3), k1(kk1), k2(kk2) {
  > ```

  If you really cannot simplify it yourself, considering wrapping it:

  ```
  KontrollSiffer(int kk1 = 0, int kk2 = 0, int i1 = 0, int i2 = 0, int i3 = 0)
      : IndividSiffer(i1, i2, i3), k1(kk1), k2(kk2) {
  ```